# How to remove the # in Backbone.js URL's

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone.js, still learning it and 1 problem I have run into is a lot of resources online are outdated and things have changed in Backbone.js since the time the resources were created.

What I am confused about is I have seen some tutorials that have nice clean urls like this
`domain.com/useer/add` but more often I am seeing `domain.com/#useer/add`

So my question is, does Backbone enable you to do the URL's like this `domain.com/useer/add` without the **#** or does that require another library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can set pushState = true like this.

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true })
```

take a look at this link for more details.
http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/

Comment: Thanks I knew you could do it with the History pushstate by itself so I wasn't sure if this was built into Backbone, i'm happy to see that it is, strange that everyone doesn't use this!  Thanks for the link too

Comment: The issue with doing things this way is that it requires that your server is setup to handle these URLs. If a user copy and pastes "domain.com/useer/add" into their browser, they should be seeing the same page/state of the site. So you'd either need your server to direct any request URI back to the root and have JS render the state or you would need to be able to render the same page/state with server-side code. The advantage to using the hash bang is that if a use copy and pastes the address it will generally work without any server-side modifications.