# How to replace "#" routes to standard routes

Tags: backbone.js

E.g:
in router.js

```
routes: { "": "home", "first": "first" }, .....
```

in page:

```
<a href="#">home</a> <a href="#first">link first page</a>
```

In the browser address bar: `www.domain.com/#first`

I want to get URL: `www.domain.com/first`

How to replace the "#" in routes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the # in Backbone.js URL's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884410/how-to-remove-the-in-backbone-js-urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true })`.

From documentation (http://backbonejs.org/#History):

> To indicate that you'd like to use HTML5 pushState support in your
>   application, use `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})`. If you'd
>   like to use pushState, but have browsers that don't support it
>   natively use full page refreshes instead, you can add {hashChange:
>   false} to the options.

Comment: it's good ,but like routes: { "first/:id": "firstdetail" },<a href="first/100">link firstdetail page</a>,cann't opend why?

Comment: solved this problem,not use "/" and use other chart
E.g 
routes: { "first::id": "firstdetail" }
in page
<a href="/first:100">link firstdetail page</a>
can open the page
thanks @saaaaaaaaasha